# Redshift Uploading Error for quote : Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x22

Tags: amazon-redshift

When trying copy S3 file to Redshift, we're facing the error as follows;

```
Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x22 found at location 2
```

0x22 means double quotations, since target data contains "," in some column like 'NO,123456', so we quote each columns by double quotations in exported csv file. 
And run the copy command like this;

```
-- copy command
copy <target_table_name> from 's3://s3-bucket-name'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' REGION 'ap-northeast-1'
REMOVEQUOTES
ESCAPE
DATEFORMAT 'auto'
TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
DELIMITER ',' 
ACCEPTINVCHARS '?'
COMPUPDATE TRUE 
STATUPDATE TRUE 
TRUNCATECOLUMNS  
EMPTYASNULL
EXPLICIT_IDS
ENCODING UTF8;
```

Also tried 'csv' option, instead of removequotes/escape, but it can't work.
I must admit there is something wrong my command, but so far, I have no idea.
Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same type of file, can you just try 
FORMAT AS CSV
TRIMBLANKS

Comment: @PeterRing  Thanks thousands, Peter!!  I tried 'FORMAT AS CSV TRIMBLANKS' and confirmed it works !! Thank you so much for your helpful advice !!